# Want to increase the respberry pi zero w hotspot area

Tags: hotspot, zero-configuration-networking

I m looking forward for a solution to increase the respberry pi hotspot length right now its 100 m approx for each respberry pi is it possible we can increase the range by using some external devices.
Or any other similar device which can have a long range hotspot connectivity.

Comment: `any other similar device` - like, commercial access points for example? To add an external antenna to the Zero W, you need a U.FL Coax Connector, a Hot air rework station, Flux Solder paste and an Antenna - or you can use a USB WiFi dongle with a decent antenna

Comment: adding antenna to PI0W https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Y648CjIiEv8

Comment: Thanks but can you tell me please by doing this how much range can we able to increase maximum ?

Comment: no, there's plenty of other instructions about doing the same thing, maybe one of them has done the tests - guaranteed to be more though

Comment: Is it an option to use a second (and more) Raspberry Pi Zero W as WiFi repeater?

Comment: this [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KonrpeVRRjc) does benchmarking